# How can I make this function to search a node of a linked list and return address of the found node?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have this function to search a node from linked list which is not properly working. If I use this function in main() and run the code, it compiles but does not work when input is given. It won't even show the message I have put in "cout<<"  I have not used "return" yet because I can't understand how to return address of the searched node.
what modification can I make to find the searched node,return address of the node when it is found and return Null when not found. (Using c++)
I'm a new learner so kindly  take that in consideration if my code is too wrong.

```
 /*
Implement a function named searchData to search a particular value.
The function should return address of the node where the search element is found
otherwise return NULL.
*/
node *searchData(int key) //Head is global variable and node is a structure.
{

while (head!=NULL)
{
    if (head->data==key)

   cout<<"Element Found";
}
head=head->link;

}
```

Comment: What is `head`? This is clearly **not** a member function, but a global function. Is `head` a global variable? And if so, should you really be modifying it here?

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` statement at the moment, so doesn't return anything. Without your definition of `node` it will be hard to reproduce. What error do you get? A compile error? Or does it sometimes work? Can you be more specific about the "not working properly" part of your question?

Comment: @scohe001 Head is a global variable. Node is a structure. And I didn't know how should i return it that is why i didn't use return yet.

Comment: @doctorlove It compiles but if i use this function in main and give input element it doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK, clearer - are you expecting the "Element found" message? Try and else and print what is in `head->data` if it doesn't match. Try to dream up ways to explore what you're created and find out what it's up to

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't actually search using the head pointer , because on advancing in search , the head will change through this line(head=head->link) and you will lose the whole list ,
so you need to have another pointer as a copy of the head.

so the code will be like this:

```
node *searchData(int key) //Head is global variable and node is a structure.
{

node * temp=head;

while (temp!=NULL)
{
if (temp->data==key)

  {
   cout<<"Element Found";
   return temp;
   temp=temp->next; //in case the key is not found yet
   }
 }
return NULL; //key was not found

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//This function takes in the linked list and key.
//This function returns the node that contains that key.
node *searchData(int key, node* mylist)
{
   node* head = mylist;

   while (head!=NULL)
   {
     if (head->data==key)
       break;
     else
       head = head->next;
   }
   return head;
}
```